# phonegap android edittext is hidden behind virtual keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I am developing an android phonegap app. i created a popup using HTML, which contains two edit fields for "username" and "password". when these fields receives focus, the soft keyboard appears and hides immediately. Can anybody say why it behaves like this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you post your little code snippet of what have you done so far??

Answer (score 0):

it must be losing focus right after too for some other reason I would suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` on your Android manifest file.That worked for me.

It's a late answer but will be helpful for someone else.